# CloudWatch Alarm in EC2 template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am setting up an AWS EC2 template based on a custom image for launching instances for a certain purpose. These instances then also need CloudWatch alarms monitoring their activity and perform some action based on them (e.g. stop instance if inactive for 30 min.).

Is there any way I can include such alarms into the EC2 template? I would like to avoid having to manually add the alarms to the instance after creation. I couldn't find this as an option anywhere in the template creation dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From management console - could not find a straight forward option.

Using EC2 Tags, Lambda and other services - might be possible - check the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/use-tags-to-create-and-maintain-amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-for-amazon-ec2-instances-part-1/)

***CloudFormation*** - you can write a CF template to create EC2 and add an alarm to it. You can continue enhancing it.

This option will make things easier once the template is created as you will not need to select various UI options whenever you launch new EC2 and add alarm.

This [template](https://github.com/nisarg1611/CloudFormationTemplates/blob/facb14be5b3d0c9db0256f632be8edc3d214bd30/EC2/EC2-Cloudwatch-SNS-CFX.yaml) will ask for instance type, will create an alarm for EC2 and publish to an SNS topic.

Verify AMI, AZ if you are logged into a different region.

```
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Description: EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.small
    AllowedValues:
      - t1.micro
      - t2.nano
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
    ConstraintDescription: It must be a valid EC2 instance type.
Resources:
  MyInstance1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: ami-05912b6333beaa478
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: KP-EC2-Lambda
      SecurityGroups:
        - launch-wizard-2
  CPUAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: CPU alarm for my instance
      AlarmActions:
      - Ref: "MyTopic1"
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
      Namespace: AWS/EC2
      Statistic: Average
      Period: '60'
      EvaluationPeriods: '3'
      Threshold: '90'
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
      - Name: InstanceId
        Value:
          Ref: "MyInstance1"
  MyTopic1:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties: 
      DisplayName: MyTopic1
      Subscription: 
        - Endpoint: "xyz@xyz.com"
          Protocol: "email"
      TopicName: MyTopic1
```

Comment: CloudFormation does sound cool. However, does it leave room for some flexibility? For example, in an EC2 template I can leave the instance type up to the person who launches an instance from that template, subject to some restrictions. Can I set similar restrictions in CloudFormation templates?

Comment: Absolutely, you can add various parameters, constrains in the template.
I will update the main answer with link to a template which will ask for instance type, create an alarm for EC2 and publish to an SNS topic.